# phpmailer received email but not attachment

Tags: phpmailer, email-attachments

I am using the below script to allow user to upload images and email it to me. I did received the email but the attachment is not included in the email. It also show the from email as root user instead of the user's email address. please help.

```
 <?php
ob_start();
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$salutation        = $_POST['salutation'];
    $firstname         = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname          = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email             = $_POST['email'];
    $photo             = $_FILES['photo'];

isset($_POST['submit']);
$active_keys = array();
foreach($_FILES[$photo]['name'] as $key => $filename)
{
if(!empty($filename))
{
    $active_keys[] = $key;
}    }

foreach($active_keys as $key)
{    switch(exif_imagetype($_FILES[$photo]['tmp_name'][$key])) {
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    break;
default:
    echo "{";
    echo        "error: 'This is no photo..'\n";
    echo "}";
    exit(0);
} }
$message = "Photo submitted by: $salutation $firstname $lastname.  <br>Comments: $comments.<br>terms:$terms.";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = ($email);
$mail->AddAddress('info@domain.com');

$mail->Subject  = "Submitted Photos";
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

foreach($FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo) {
if(!empty($photo)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($photo);
}}

$mail->Send();

header("Location: thankyou.php");
   exit();     

?>
```

Comment: change foreach($FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo) { to foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
foreach($FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo) {
```

to

```
foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That help with the attachment.  What about the Root User on the from email.  Is there a way to make it showing the email of the user?  thx.